# Creating file on server in asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I want to create file and this file must create in folder App_Data in my project.

How I can do it?

```
 FileInfo MyFile = new FileInfo("~\\App_Data\\asd.txt");
            if (MyFile.Exists == false)
            {
                FileStream fs = MyFile.Create();
                fs.Close();
            }
```

I get this error

Could not find part of the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\asd.txt".

Comment: Provide a proper information.show the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code

```
FileInfo MyFile = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~\\App_Data\\asd.txt"));
```